# Chart to be created using database details

Tags: php, jquery, charts

I have chart code as below:

```
 var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Mychart.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                    }, {
                        name: 'New York',
                        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Berlin',
                        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                    }, {
                        name: 'London',
                        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                    }]
                });


            });
```

I want to pass countries name from my database table country i.e. array of country names and similarly data also from database to be passed to series.

Can anybody help me how this is to be passed in this jquery using php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a file and retrieve data from DB, like:

```
<? $result = mysql_query($query); 

   echo "series: [";

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo "{";
     echo "name:'".$row['cityname']."',";
     echo "data: [".$row['data']."]";
     echo "}";
   }

   echo "];";

?>
```

If your *data* is another array you can loop that too, just remember to append strings correctly.

Comment: why don't you go on and correct my answer or post yours? I vote to cancel mine since it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much Lex, it was really quick and great help for me

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best practice to pass data you need is **json-object**, e.g.:

```
<?php 
$countries = array(
  'france' => array(
     'capital' => 'Paris',
  ),
  'spain' => array(
     'capital' => 'Madrid',
  )
);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var countries = <?php echo json_encode($countries); ?>;
  alert(countries.spain.capital)      # ==> returns Madrid
</script>
```